# How to fix web server on Mac OS 10.11 and enable PHP

Tags: php, macos, apache, webserver

I was trying to enable PHP by following some instructions (can't find that darn page again), and seem to have messed things up. Not only can't I see my one line `phpinfo.php` file `<?php phpinfo();?>`, but I can no longer load html files from `Library/WebServer/Documents` or `~/Sites`. I could before I messed with things. However, I know that apache is running because going to `localhost` gives the the "It Works!" page.

Here is my apache conf file sans commented lines:

**`/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`**:

```
ServerRoot "/usr"

Listen 80

LoadModule authn_file_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module libexec/apache2/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module libexec/apache2/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule include_module libexec/apache1/mod_include.so
LoadModule filter_module libexec/apache2/mod_filter.so
LoadModule mime_module libexec/apache2/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module libexec/apache2/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule env_module libexec/apache2/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module libexec/apache2/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module libexec/apache2/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module libexec/apache2/mod_version.so
LoadModule proxy_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_scgi.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_express_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_express.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module libexec/apache2/mod_slotmem_shm.so
LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
LoadModule unixd_module libexec/apache2/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule status_module libexec/apache2/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module libexec/apache2/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule negotiation_module libexec/apache2/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module libexec/apache2/mod_dir.so
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
LoadModule hfs_apple_module libexec/apache2/mod_hfs_apple.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
User _www
Group _www

</IfModule>

ServerAdmin me@example.com

ServerName me@example.com

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>


DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "^\.([Hh][Tt]|[Dd][Ss]_[Ss])">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

<Files "rsrc">
    Require all denied
</Files>
<DirectoryMatch ".*\.\.namedfork">
    Require all denied
</DirectoryMatch>

ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log" common

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAliasMatch ^/cgi-bin/((?!(?i:webobjects)).*$) "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/$1"
</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>

<Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /private/etc/apache2/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>


TraceEnable off
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you missing virtualhost default setting looks like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
    ServerName localhost
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```